# Mapview application withh different icons in Iphone

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

Please some body give me some idea I am new on mapview application.

I need to display a map, when my app get loaded its will display a map in this map it will display some icons that icon must be dynamically and must be perform some action as we consider we have to display dynamically button on map view and perform different action with this button.

like if 5 icons come from server it will display 5 icons in map (icon must be dynamically come from server and display in google map.).

Answer (score 0):

you can use the MKPlacemark as a "button"

first get location from server

```
- (void)addAnnotations:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate {

// Pin 1
    CLLocationCoordinate2D  coordinate1 = {
        x.x, y.y
    };
    NSDictionary *address = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Pin 1", @"Country", @"1", @"Thoroughfare", nil];
    MKPlacemark *pin = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinate1 addressDictionary:address];
    [mapView addAnnotation:pin];
```

set its callout as a button to perform some action

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView: (MKMapView *) mapView viewForAnnotation: (id<MKAnnotation>) annotation
{
    MKPlacemark *placemark = annotation;


    MKPinAnnotationView *pin = (MKPinAnnotationView *) [self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier: @"asdf"];
    if (pin == nil)
    {
        pin = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation: annotation reuseIdentifier: @"asdf"] autorelease];
    }
    else
    {
        pin.annotation = annotation;
    }
    pin.canShowCallout = YES;
    pin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
```

also set the pins image to whatever you like, so the pin looks like a button

```
   pin.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"some-pic.png"];
```

and tell it what to do

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control;{
//code whatever should be done
```

Comment: Thanks for that detail do you have any dome code related this please mend me or please give all details over view that how to used these code.How can display dynamically icons and every icons have particular longitude and latitude value and i have to display all in same map.